# RubyMine Will Not Open .sqlite3 Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubymine

I tried opening a .sqlite3 file for the first time in RubyMine.  Since it was not recognized by default it gave me the association choice which I set to .sqlite files.

So everything should be working OK.

However, when I click on the file to open, RubyMine does nothing. (not even an error)

I searched for a plugin that would read sqlite3 files but did not find any.  Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby mine can actually read those files you just have to set it up in the database tool window.

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/database-tool-window.html

Comment: I discovered this a while ago but neglected to post here.  Thank you for doing so.